# React-native 'name is null' when playing Sound from a fetched file

Tags: react-native, audio, blob, fetch-api, arraybuffer

I am creating an app with a text-to-speech functionality. You click a button on the front-end (React Native), and it requests the server (Node.js) to ask Google TTS to generate an MP3 file, which I would then like the app to play aloud.

However, when I run it on my android phone, I keep on getting the same error 'name is null' from my front-end when creating and playing the sound object from the server response. I know the server-side URL works because when I type it in browser, I am able to download the MP3 directly.

I haven't been able to find much via documentation, so have been using ChatGPT to help me debug, but to no avail... I have tried a bunch of alternative fetch (rn-fetch-blob) and encoders, but nothing has helped.

Thank you very much for your help <3

Below are the relevant functions server-side and client-side:

Index.js (server)

```
        app.get('/tts', async (req, res) => {
        const text = 'hello, world!';
    
        // Construct the request
        const request = {
            input: { text: text },
            // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)
            voice: { languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL' },
            // select the type of audio encoding
            audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3' },
        };
    
        try {
            // Performs the text-to-speech request
            const [response] = await textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(request);
    
            // Set response headers to indicate MP3 content
            res.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
            res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.mp3');
            // Send the audio content back to the client
            console.log(response.audioContent);
            res.send(response.audioContent);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    });
```

Client-side function for playing the sound:

```
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
       const speakMessage = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('* URL - hidden for privacy reasons :) *');
                const audioArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    
                // Convert ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array
                const audioUint8Array = new Uint8Array(audioArrayBuffer);
    
                // Create blob from Uint8Array
                const blob = new Blob([audioUint8Array], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
    
                // Check if filename is available (replace 'output.mp3' with actual filename if available)
                const filename = 'output.mp3';
    
                // Ensure filename is not null or empty
                if (!filename) {
                    console.error('Error: Invalid filename');
                    return;
                }
    
                console.log('Blob:', blob);
                console.log('Filename:', filename);
    
                // Create a new Sound instance from the blob
                const sound = new Sound(blob, filename, (error) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('Error loading sound:', error);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Sound loaded successfully');
                        // Play the sound
                        sound.play((success) => {
                            if (success) {
                                console.log('Sound played successfully');
                            } else {
                                console.log('Playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching or playing audio:', error);
            }
        };
```

Mainly debugged using ChatGPT, it made me try a bunch of different ways of fetching the file (axios, fetch) and encoders like Uint8Array, Buffer, etc...,
Tried to explicitly give the sound a filename.